# Replace three or more consecutive whitespaces with tabs in linux

Tags: linux, tabs, whitespace

How can I change all instances of three or more consecutive white spaces with tabs in a file in linux?

Comment: You really didn't think this through, did you. Stop and think: do you want every 3 spaces to be replaced with a tab? Or every occurrence of 3 or more spaces to be replaced with a single tab? What if the spaces occur after some text? What if they occur within double quotes?

Comment: Every occurrence of 3 or more consecutive spaces to be replaced with a single tab. I did think it through actually, I just don't know linux commands at all really. Like if there's a line of text like: "foo     bar     foo" Just replace those 2 instances of consecutive whitespaces with a single tab. There are no double quotes in my file either. Edit: seems like stackoverflow deletes excessive whitespace. Before and after the bar in that example line there's supposed to be 3 or more whitespaces.

Comment: But don't replace single or double spaces with tabs.

Answer (score 0):

to stop stackoverflow from eating whitespace. assume you want to replace 3 a's with a single x.

example data:

```
echo "123aa456aaaaaa789aa0aa" > foofile
```

use sed and a regex:

```
sed -r 's/aaa+/x/g' foofile
```

output

```
123aa456x789aa0aa
```